# Highcharts is rounding off the decimal values to 0. How to avoid it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I am passing the ecpm as you can see below as ["0.4", "0.2", "0.6", "0.3"]  to be the data for y axis to draw a spline on a multi axis graph, using highcharts. But it is drawing the spline as a straight horizontal line considering the values as 0. Values on tooltip for every point is also coming as 0.

Following is the script used:

```
$('#dual-axes-line-and-column4').highcharts({
                chart: {
                    zoomType: 'xy'
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Some Matrix'
                },
                subtitle: {
                    text: ''
                },
                xAxis: [{
                    categories: perfCategoriesStr
                }],
                yAxis: [
                    { // Primary yAxis
                    labels: {
                        format: '{value}',
                        style: {
                            color: '#89A54E'
                        }
                    },
                    title: {
                        text: 'Views',
                        style: {
                            color: '#89A54E'
                        }
                    },
                    opposite:false
                }, { // Secondary yAxis
                    title: {
                        text: 'Revenue in $',
                        style: {
                            color: '#4572A7'
                        }
                    },
                    labels: {
                        format: '{value}',
                        style: {
                            color: '#4572A7'
                        }
                    },
                    opposite: true
                }, { // Secondary yAxis
                    title: {
                        text: 'eCPM in $',
                        style: {
                            color: '#4572A7'
                        }
                    },
                    labels: {
                        format: '{value}',
                        style: {
                            color: '#4572A7'
                        }
                    },
                    opposite: true
                }],
                tooltip: {
                    shared: true
                },
                legend: {
                    layout: 'vertical',
                    align: 'left',
                    x: 70,
                    verticalAlign: 'top',
                    y: 10,
                    floating: true,
                    backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF'
                },
                series: [{
                    name: 'Views',
                    color: '#4572A7',
                    type: 'column',

                    data: views,
                    tooltip: { 
                        valueSuffix: ' views'
                    }

                }, {
                    name: 'Revenue',
                    color: '#89A54E',
                    type: 'spline',
                    yAxis:1,
                    data: revenue,
                    tooltip: {
                        valuePrefix: '$ '
                    }
                }, {
                    name: 'eCPM',
                    color: '#000000',
                    type: 'spline',
                    yAxis: 1,
                    data: ecpm,
                    tooltip: {
                        valuePrefix: '$ '
                    }
                }]
            });
```

Comment: Can you also post in the highcharts code? Possibly the options parameter?

Comment: Thanks @Omkar for coming up.

Answer (score 1):

Just figured it out. The values passed should be a number rather than a string. Its working fine if we are passing javascript numbers in an array instead of string as you can see in the question.